# DELAYED User at MySQL

Tags: mysql, security, insert, process

mysql> show processlist;

```
| Id    | User    | Host                    | db           | Command        | Time | State              | Info             |
| 27098 | DELAYED | localhost               | placeholder  | Delayed insert |  111 | Waiting for INSERT |                  |
```

I'm finding this process as suspicious, but nothing in ps, netstat, cron.
How to get more info about that process? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once someone executes [**INSERT DELAYED**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-delayed.html), a system thread will open in order to track and mitigate INSERTs of this kind. [MySQL 5.6 deprecates it and 5.7 does not support it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-delayed.html).

What is more, in terms of MySQL Replication, Slaves will completely ignore an [**INSERT DELAYED**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-delayed.html) command from a Master and execute them as a standard INSERT.

Please read the [MySQL 5.5 Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-delayed.html) on this for further info.

## UPDATE 2016-07-05 11:30 EDT

Since [you are interested in process/client, which originates this "INSERT DELAYED" query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142926/delayed-user-at-mysql/142937#comment271216_142937), you should look at the thread states. [**The MySQL 5.5 Documentation describes them well**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delayed-insert-thread-states.html):

> **States associated with a connection thread that processes an INSERT DELAYED statement from the client**:
>
> - allocating local table : The thread is preparing to feed rows to the delayed-insert handler
>   thread.
> - Creating delayed handler : The thread is creating a handler for DELAYED inserts.
> - got handler lock : This occurs before the allocating local table state and after the waiting for handler lock state, when the connection thread gets access to the delayed-insert handler thread.
> - got old table : This occurs after the waiting for handler open state. The delayed-insert handler thread has signaled that it has ended its initialization phase, which includes opening the table for delayed inserts.
> - storing row into queue : The thread is adding a new row to the list of rows that the delayed-insert handler thread must insert.
> - waiting for delay_list : This occurs during the initialization phase when the thread is trying
>   to find the delayed-insert handler thread for the table, and before attempting to gain access to the list of delayed-insert threads.
> - waiting for handler insert : An INSERT DELAYED handler has processed all pending inserts and is waiting for new ones.
> - waiting for handler lock : This occurs before the allocating local table state when the connection thread waits for access to the delayed-insert handler thread.
> - waiting for handler open : This occurs after the Creating delayed handler state and before the got old table state. The delayed-insert handler thread has just been started, and the connection thread is waiting for it to initialize.
>
> **States associated with a delayed-insert handler thread that inserts the rows:**
>
> - insert : The state that occurs just before inserting rows into the table.
> - reschedule : After inserting a number of rows, the delayed-insert thread sleeps to let other threads do work.
> - upgrading lock : A delayed-insert handler is trying to get a lock for the table to insert rows.
> - Waiting for INSERT : A delayed-insert handler is waiting for a connection thread to add rows to the queue (see storing row into queue).

Comment: Thank you, Ronaldo, for answer.

But I'm interesting about process/client, which originates this "INSERT DELAYED" query.

Comment: With looking to above answer and slow log misunderstanding disappeared.